# Deploying SharePoint for testing purposes

Tags: sharepoint

I'm a developer trying to learn to work with SharePoint.  I'd like to install SharePoint on my desktop at home which is running Windows 7 Professional.  If I am going to be doing everything from this one machine (i.e. not distributing any responsibilities to other machines) then will this work, or do I necessarily need to install SharePoint on a machine with a server operating system?

Comment: Good question, and good answer :)

Comment: @BretFisher Thanks, someone else didn't think so apparently though.  I guess they saw the word "home" in my question and decided it was off topic 6 months after I'd already answered it myself, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just found the answer to my question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx.